# Supremum over ellipsoid set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

In [Boyd's Convex Optimization Textbook](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), page 157, it is stated:

$
\mathrm{sup}\{a_i^T x\; |\; a_i\in\mathcal{E}_i \} = \bar a_i^T x + \mathrm{sup}\{u^T P_i^T x\; |\; \lVert u \rVert_2 \leq 1 \} = \bar a_i^T x + \lVert P_i^T x \rVert_2
$

But I do not see how

$\mathrm{sup}\{u^T P_i^T x\; |\; \lVert u \rVert_2 \leq 1 \} = \lVert P_i^T x \rVert_2$ ?

Also, is it supremum over $a_i$ ?

Comment: For the sake of the audience: the model being solved is$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & c^T x \\ \text{subject to} & a_i^T x \leq b_i ~ \text{for all}~a_i\in\mathcal{E}_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots,m\end{array}$$In other words, the problem involves $m$ separate inequality constraints, and in each case, there is a search over an entire ellipse to find the worst-case result. The transformation described here eliminates the search over the ellipses by converting each of the $m$ constraints to a second-order-cone constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a mistype on the authors' part. What they are really trying to say is this:

$\forall i=1,2,\ldots,$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R^n$, we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\sup\{a_i^Tx \text{ s.t } a_i \in \mathcal E_i\} &= \sup\{x^T(\bar{a}_i + P_iu) \text{ s.t } \|u\| \le 1\}\\
&= x^T\bar{a}_i + \sup\{x^TP_iu \text{ s.t } \|u\| \le 1\} \\
&=: x^T\bar{a}_i + \|P_ix\|_* \text { (definition of dual norm of the vector $v := P_iu$)}\\
&= x^T\bar{a}_i + \|P_ix\| \text{ (the $\ell_2$-norm is self-dual)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: $z \in a_i$?    $a_i$ is not a set, did you mean $z\in\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: OK, sorry I typed this from a limited terminal (phone). Fixed. The sup is on $\mathcal E_i$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure I see where the original iss wrong. Your derivation is correct of course.